# Divergent series solution to PDE - Failure of Cauchy-Kovaleska

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the diffusion equation

$\partial_t u =\partial_{xx} u$

where $x \in [-1,1]$ and $t>0$, subject to IC

$u(x,0)= \frac{1}{1-x}$.

If I construct a power series in $t$ at the origin using the PDE+IC as in Cauchy-Kovaleska theorem (CK) I get

$u(0,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n!}{n!} t^n$

which is clearly divergent $\forall t \neq 0$.

My question is why did this happen? And what changes should be made to get a convergent series? CK only requires analicity in a neighbourhood of the origin. And although $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is not analytic, it is analytic in a nbh of $0$. I guess what I am trying to understand with this question is a simple case where CK hypothesis fail and why.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's actually the example which Kovalevskaya herself gave to demonstrate the neccesity of one of the conditions in the theorem. Namely, the order of differentiation for the variable $t$ in the lhs should be greater or equal to the order of the rhs differential operator.

Comment: Thank you. Actually the example she gave was different (although almost the same). She used $u(0,x)=(x^2+1)^{-1}$, at least that is what wikipedia says...

Comment: @Nik here it is stated that the first example is made by Kovalevskaya and both are mentioned: http://books.google.ru/books?id=vitoIs2Cr7oC&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false